# convert PIL Image object to File object

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Is there any way (without saving a file to disk and then deleting it) to convert a PIL Image object to a File object?

Comment: are you using django? and you need file object like django?

Comment: @NeErAj KuMaR I'm not using Django no,
this is for a discord bot and discord uploads only accept File objects

Answer (score 13):

Let's look at what a file object is.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fp:
    print(fp)
    # <_io.TextIOWrapper name='test.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html has more on the subject as well.

I suspect that for your purposes, it would be enough to have a BytesIO object.

```
import io
from PIL import Image
im = Image.new("RGB", (100, 100))
b = io.BytesIO()
im.save(b, "JPEG")
b.seek(0)
```

But if you really want the same object, then -

```
fp = io.TextIOWrapper(b)
```

Comment: I need this to upload qr code to s3. but it show error . UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: Could you provide a sample image?

Answer (score 2):

Use a temporary file from the `tempfile` standard library.

```py
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
from PIL import Image

fp = TemporaryFile()

img = Image.new("RGB", (100, 100))
img.save(fp, "PNG")
```

Don't forget to reset the position!

```py
fp.seek(0)
```

Closing the file will remove it

```py
fp.close()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html