Is there a way to scale up an image and rotate text in PyPDF
Working on a mini project to print tickets on an older printer, formatted the tickets to fit on the printer and print. But now they want the format of the ticket to be different. I need to scale up the QR code, but I don't want to have to save the image of it and then add it back, is there anyway to take the image from the PDF and edit it using Pillow and reinsert it? I haven't looked much into rotating the text yet but worse comes to worse I'd just rotate the entire page because it doesn't matter what way the QR code is facing.
My main problem is coming up because I don't want to save and re open the image from inside the pdf as to me it's not efficient enough and takes up more unnecessary space. If it really comes to it I can just create a temp folder but I would rather not go to that. I've tried extracting the bytes and put that into PIL but that didn't work, I can't use the typical open method because it wants a file path that I can't give because I don't want to save it.
As for the resizing part, this is definitely a duplicate of this question, but the answer Martin Thoma gave for me doesn't work, when I do img = img.image.resize((300, 300), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS) the method is blank as if its not recognizing the Pillow imported method or its not recognizing the .image can be used as a pillow starting point? If I can make the image inside the pdf an instance of PIL I will be fine
Anyway here is what I have in regards to cropping the original big pdf into smaller tickets and where I want to adjust the scale of QR code and rotate the text.
while pagesAdded < num_of_validations and pagesAdded < 30:
            
    ## Defining upper left and lower right hand corners of each validations
            page.mediabox.upper_left = [10+208*(pagesAdded%3), height-90-79*(rowCount%10)]
            page.mediabox.lower_right = [175+208*(pagesAdded%3), height-30-79*(rowCount%10)]

            ## Where I want to rotate text and scale up QR code
            img = page.images[0]
            print(img)
            print(img.data)
            print(img.image)
            
            pil_img = # Open img into pillow here

            pil_img.resize((250,250), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
            print("After resize")
            print(pil_img.data)
            img.replace(pil_img, quality = 80)

            ## Add newly defined "page" (validation) to the new pdf
            writer.add_page(page)

Ultimately, I just want something that works, so if I can refine Martin Thoma's suggestion from the other post, or just figure out how to extract the data from the png inside the pdf to open in pillow either one would work.

I would start with checking that your image after opening is in an acceptable format. I believe numpy arrays are acceptable to most if not all image processing libraries. Then perform your scaling from there.  Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57657765/read-pdf-as-a-picture

"for me doesn't work" is not really helpful without a PDF file or further details/analysis.

@epR8GaYuh Very fair haha, first real post on stackoverflow so still a bit new. I completed that project and have since moved on but will try to improve on my asking of questions if I need to post another! :)
